# Site whitening when loading

Tags: wordpress

I created a site with WordPress
I also use the Promosys template
When I open the site, the site is white for 30 seconds and then it shows the information
Interestingly, the site is loaded but shows a white screen and is displayed after 30 seconds

I am using the wprocket plugin, I felt that there might be a problem with this plugin, I disabled it but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

first, try to increase PHP memory limit by adding the code below to your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

could be a problem with your theme as well.
try with a default wordpress theme and let us know how it goes after adding the code.

Comment: your website takes forever to load. it could be many reasons like too much active plugins, your host service, too much css and js files being used.